# Automate file reading Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, file, hosting

I am making a file storage website for myself, pretty much just for practice. I have the code working but right now I have a massive JSON file that includes the name of every file that I want to have on the website.

Is there a way to have the JS read the files automatically? If it helps, all of the files are in a single folder.

My file structure looks like this;

```
root
|-HTML
|-Style
| |-CSS
| |-JS
|  |-Downloads.js (this is the js file that controls downloads)
|-Files
  |-files (this folder holds all the actual files)
  |-img (this folder holds the images I use as thumbnails)
```

Comment: Using Nodejs or from within the browser?

Comment: From within the browser, no (for obvious security reasons). Using Node, very simply with [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback).

Comment: What if the files are also hosted on the sever? @JeremyThille

Comment: What do you mean _also_ on the server? You mean on the same server as... the server? Well that's the whole point, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible with pure Javascript since it's executed on browsers, file handling is prohibited for security reasons. Imagine if someone create a javascript script that modifies something in our computers, like changing files, configurations or even installing viruses... it would be a great mess.

What you can do is to install Node.js in your machine and use [JSON Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) to serve your JSON file through an API. Then you get it through an AJAX request at your javascript code.